# trying to print top view of binary tree using pre-order

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

below two codes should work same way but giving different output. I tried to debug the code as best as i could but couldn't find the bug.

CODE1:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

typedef struct label
{
    struct node* root;
    int disp;
}label;

int main() {

    struct node* n1 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n2 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n3 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n4 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n5 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n6 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n7 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n8 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n9 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n10 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n11 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n12 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n13 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n1->data = 1;
    n2->data = 2;
    n3->data = 3;
    n4->data = 4;
    n5->data = 5;
    n6->data = 6;
    n7->data = 7;
    n8->data = 8;
    n9->data = 9;
    n10->data = 10;
    n11->data = 11;
    n12->data = 12;
    n13->data = 13;
    n1 -> left = n2;
    n1 -> right = n3;
    n2 -> left = n4;
    n2 -> right = n5;
    n4 -> left = n4 -> right = NULL;
    n5 -> left = n5 -> right = NULL;
    n3 -> left = n6;
    n3 -> right = n7;
    n6 -> left = n6 -> right = NULL;
    n7 -> left = n8;
    n7 -> right = NULL;
    n8 -> left = n9;
    n8 -> right = NULL;
    n9 -> left = n10;
    n9 -> right = NULL;
    n10 -> left = n11;
    n10 -> right = NULL;
    n11 -> left = n12;
    n11 -> right = NULL;
    n12 -> left = n13;
    n12 -> right = NULL;
    n13 -> left = NULL;
    n13 -> right = NULL;



    node* root = n1;

    stack<label*> s;
    map<int, int> m;

    label* var = new label();
    var -> root = root;
    var -> disp = 0;

    label* var1 = new label();

    s.push(var);

    while(!s.empty()) {
        m.insert( pair <int, int> ( var -> disp, var -> root -> data) );

        s.pop();
        if( var -> root -> right != NULL ) {
            var1 -> root = var -> root -> right;
            var1 -> disp = var -> disp + 1;
            s.push(var1);

        }
        if( var -> root -> left != NULL ) {
            var1 -> root = var -> root -> left;
            var1 -> disp = var -> disp - 1;
            s.push(var1);

        }
        if(!s.empty()) {

            var -> root = s.top() -> root;
            var -> disp = s.top() -> disp;
        }
    }
    map<int, int> :: iterator itr;
    for( itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++ ) {
        cout<< itr -> second << endl;
    }

}
```

CODE2:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

typedef struct label
{
    struct node* root;
    int disp;
}label;

int main() {

    struct node* n1 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n2 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n3 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n4 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n5 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n6 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n7 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n8 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n9 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n10 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n11 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n12 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* n13 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n1->data = 1;
    n2->data = 2;
    n3->data = 3;
    n4->data = 4;
    n5->data = 5;
    n6->data = 6;
    n7->data = 7;
    n8->data = 8;
    n9->data = 9;
    n10->data = 10;
    n11->data = 11;
    n12->data = 12;
    n13->data = 13;
    n1 -> left = n2;
    n1 -> right = n3;
    n2 -> left = n4;
    n2 -> right = n5;
    n4 -> left = n4 -> right = NULL;
    n5 -> left = n5 -> right = NULL;
    n3 -> left = n6;
    n3 -> right = n7;
    n6 -> left = n6 -> right = NULL;
    n7 -> left = n8;
    n7 -> right = NULL;
    n8 -> left = n9;
    n8 -> right = NULL;
    n9 -> left = n10;
    n9 -> right = NULL;
    n10 -> left = n11;
    n10 -> right = NULL;
    n11 -> left = n12;
    n11 -> right = NULL;
    n12 -> left = n13;
    n12 -> right = NULL;
    n13 -> left = NULL;
    n13 -> right = NULL;



    node* root = n1;

    stack<label*> s;
    map<int, int> m;

    label* var = new label();
    var -> root = root;
    var -> disp = 0;


    s.push(var);

    while(!s.empty()) {
        m.insert( pair <int, int> ( var -> disp, var -> root -> data) );
        s.pop();
        if( var -> root -> right != NULL ) {
            label* var1 = new label();
            var1 -> root = var -> root -> right;
            var1 -> disp = var -> disp + 1;
            s.push(var1);   
        }
        if( var -> root -> left != NULL ) {
            label* var2 = new label();
            var2 -> root = var -> root -> left;
            var2 -> disp = var -> disp - 1;
            s.push(var2);
        }
        if(!s.empty()) {
            var -> root = s.top() -> root;
            var -> disp = s.top() -> disp;
        }
    }
    map<int, int> :: iterator itr;
    for( itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++ ) {
        cout<< itr -> second << endl;
    }

}
```

Code 2 is giving right output but Code 1 is not.
In Code2 two local label variables are created and in 
Code1 one local label variable is created and values are overidden.

[image: Picture of created binary tree]

Comment: This code is for `C++` not `C` and if it is of `C++` then why `malloc` has been used instead of `new` and if it belongs to `C` then why `malloc` has been typecasted and these libraries have been used??

Comment: What is the output of both codes? How is one right and one not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say, in CODE2 you create 2 local variables. While technically, you are right, I guess there is some misunderstanding:

Looking at line

```
label* var1 = new label();
```

within your loop:
You create a *local* variable, *and* data on the heap (the memory you allocate via `new label()` ). This memory stays there even in the next iteration.

You then push the pointer to that allocated memory onto  your stack.
You probably think that the content of the memory you allocated is copied/pushed onto the stack.
This is not true. 
What is copied onto the stack is a copy of the *pointer to the memory*.
The allocated memory is not touched in any ways.

Since in CODE2 new memory is allocated each time you iterate over your loop, the pointers on the stack point to *distinct* memory areas (distinct instances of your `label` struct).

In CODE1, you don't create memory each time, but just allocate *once* and reuse the same memory location in every iteration.

You push the pointer (in `var1`) to this location onto the stack, but since it is always the same pointer, all the pointers on the stack point to the same memory address (the same instance of your `label` struct).

Whenever you do your

```
var1 -> root = var -> root -> right;
var1 -> disp = var -> disp + 1;
```

Since `var1` always points to the same memory, you just overwrite *the same* location over and over again.

To offer a simple analogon:

It is like whenever you do a `var1 = new label()` you take a new box, label it with a number. You remove whatever is in there, then put new stuff into it.
When you do your push onto the stack, it is like you writing this number down onto a list of numbers.

In CODE2, you take a *new* empty box in every iteration, label it with a *new* number, put your stuff in, then write new new number down your list on the sheet of paper.

IN CODE1 , you only got *ONE* box.
In each iteration, you take this box again, remove what you put in there, put something new in, and add the number of the box - the same number each time - to the list on your sheet of paper.

Off course, the this box always contains just what you put into it in the last iteration. All other stuff you put into it the iterations before is lost because you replaced it.

Another, albeit in this case, minor issue is that you never free the memory you allocate. It does not matter too much in this case since upon process termination the memory will be freed anyhow, but it's a bad habbit which in more complicated programs will lead to mem leaks and final process termination.

Comment: such a silly mistake .. thanks for the clarification @Micheal

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, but you can simply allocate all nodes on the stack, no need for `malloc`/`new` here. Example:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

int main() {
    node a{1};
    node c{3};
    node b{2, &a, &c};
}
```